# How to change Messagebox Background Image

Tags: c#

Can someone help me regarding how to change the background image of `MessageBox.Show();` I can't find it in the properties window

```
MessageBox.Show("hello");
```

Comment: You can't... Create your own message box to able to

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19711/Creating-A-Custom-Message-Box-Part-2

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately. From your question, it is not clear whether you are referring to WinForms or WPF.

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageBox` isn't directly customisable. For that you'll need to roll your own using a `Form` and call `ShowDialog()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using the standard message box. You can make your own or use an existing such as [WPF Message Box](http://messagebox.codeplex.com/) ([Nuget package here](http://nuget.org/packages/MessageBox/))

Comment: so your saying that i would create a form and turn it as a MessageBox?

Comment: Yes, if you use WinForms then make a new form. If you use WPF then make a new window. Or re-use an existing one such as the one I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense saves lives.

`MessageBox.Show()` has several overloads, one of which you can specify a `MessageBoxIcon`, I don't believe there's any native support for using your own custom icon (you'd have to create your own version of `MessageBox` to do that) but you *can* use an icon identified by the `enum`.